# Gitlab CI / Docker: Use custom image for job

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

This is how I do some linter test (eslint).

```
linter:
  image: ubuntu:16.04
  stage: test
  tags:
    - testing
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install nodejs-legacy -yqq
    - apt-get install curl -yqq
    - curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
    - meteor npm install eslint eslint-plugin-react
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx .
```

But with this every test will have to install the packages to the ubuntu image, which takes time.

So I thought to build a image with exact this. I came up with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -yqq
RUN apt-get install curl -yqq
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Then I do

```
$ docker build -t linter-testing:latest .
```

and this yml file:

```
linter:
  image: linter-testing:latest
  stage: test
  tags:
    - testing
  before_script:
    - meteor npm install eslint eslint-plugin-react
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx .
```

But it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: repository linter-testing not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

So why is this image not existing, althoug `docker images` shows me exact that image...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit your `config.toml` file which is in `/etc/gitlab-runner` on your runner machine with the following

```
[runners.docker]
  pull_policy = "if-not-present"
```

See related issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1905).

Comment: The file should be in `/etc/gitlab-runner`. I edited the answer with that info.

Comment: It should already exist. You might need to edit it as root though. Just find the `[runners.docker]` section and add/modify `pull_policy = "if-not-present"`

Comment: What if the `[runners.docker]` section does not exist? I have two lines in mine and I have not registered my runner. I use it for local CI config development and debugging purposes.

Comment: @ojrask The `[runners.docker]` is part of a runner's configuration so if you have not registered any runners then it's normal that you don't have it in there. I don't know of any other way to get the desired behavior though.

Comment: Sounds like I would need to install a full Gitlab instance just to get the configs to work, as the config is not even read properly for `exec docker` commands. Silly as the main point of using the runner locally would be to test CI configs and unpublished CI container images. :)