# How to use GitLab CI with a custom Docker image?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I made a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk
EXPOSE 8080
```

and built an image using:

```
docker build -t test .
```

I installed and configured a docker GitLab CI runner and now I would like to use this runner with my `test` image. So I wrote the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: test

run:
  script:
    - echo "Hello world!"
```

But to my disappointment, the local `test` image that I can use on my machine was not found.

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.2 (6d06f2e)
  on martin-docker-rawip (70747a61)
Using Docker executor with image test ...
Using docker image sha256:fa91c6ea64ce4b9b44672c6e56eed8312d0ec2afc80730cbee7754bc448ea22b for predefined container...
Pulling docker image test ...
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: repository test not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

I do not even know what is going on anymore. How can I make the runner aware of this image that I made?

Comment: Post your gitlab-ci-multi-runner command that you have used

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am not sure what you mean. I did not run that command directly. I just commit my changes to `gitlab-ci.yml` and the process is triggered automatically.

Comment: Each Gitlab runner has an executor, which determines how and where the script you made gets executed (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#using-gitlab-runner). So if it is a Shell or SSH runner and you have build the image on that runner host then this can work

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using a docker executor. So this may be the reason it does not work. Maybe I can set up a local docker registry and serve my test image from there...

Comment: Yes, because it will spinup a new container everytime

Comment: What about this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481746/6654146 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab CI / Docker: Use custom image for job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481618/gitlab-ci-docker-use-custom-image-for-job)

Comment: For other people wondering how to use custom Docker images on GitLab instances they do not have control on: if it is configured correctly, you should be able to make GitLab pull your Docker image from Docker hub. So build your image, and push it on your user/org account on Docker hub.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same question. And I found the answer here: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/runner-cant-use-local-docker-images/5507/6

Add the following in the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
[runners.docker]
# more config for the runner here...
pull_policy = "if-not-present"
```

More info here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#how-pull-policies-work

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client rsync -y
```

On the runner I build the image:

```
docker build -t node_rsync .
```

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the project using this runner.

```
image: node_rsync

job:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # now in the custom docker image
    #- 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh-add <(tr '@' '\n' <<< "$STAGING_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode)
    # now in the custom docker image
    #- apt-get install -y rsync
  script:
    - rsync -rav -e ssh --exclude='.git/' --exclude='.gitlab-ci.yml' --delete-excluded ./ $STAGING_USER@$STAGING_SERVER:./deploy/
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - ssh
```